# The minimal path to build all Warframes?

Tags: warframe

In regard of planet unlocking and ease of part building and resource collecting.
From the starting Warframes not picking Mag is best (what I did) as she becomes accessible early. The order would be:

### Start

Drops from planet bosses, easy resources

1. Exaclibur
2. Rhino (Venus)
3. Mag (Mars)
4. Nyx (Phorid, any Infestation)
5. Ember (Saturn)
6. Valkyr (Jupiter)

### Midterm

Require extra steps for blueprints or resources

1. Oberon (Eximus, Orokin)

### Complex

1. Hydroid (requires Vay Hek mission, Argon Crystals)

### Final

Anything prime?

Which one next...?

Comment: I think you are wrong about hydroid. His blueprints do indeed drop on earth, but on a secret mission. To gain access to that mission you need to farm beacons on ceres, wich is a fairly high level planet. Read this wiki page for more info about dropping hydroid
http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Councilor_Vay_Hek

Ever wondered why you don't see a lot of hydroid?

About oberon, i dont see the problem about his parts. His requirements are pretty similar to those you listed above

Comment: @Jubatus You are right, Hydroid requires more work, so he is more mid time Warframe. Oberon parts drop only from Eximus enemies and Derelict and Void missions though.

Comment: I have to be honest, Hydroid seems more like a mid/late warframe. Farming beacons is really hard work, since those enemies spawn very rarely, and the missions are fairly difficult. So you better put him aside for now. Oberon shouldnt be that difficult, his drops are fairly frequent, and void mission arent difficult and provide very interesting rewards. You'll find yourself in the void more time then you think :)

Comment: A lot of these answers will be very opinionated, and for very good reason. If you taxi a player, you can acquire ANY warframe in any order you wish.   If you do void missions, you can get the Primes even before you even touch any mission on any planet (by getting a taxi).  The order to get Warframes is very opinionanted and as such I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, I'm going to say that there isn't really a "minimal" build path to build all of the warframes. I recommend farming bosses as you unlock them because this not only gets you the parts for whichever frame they have, but you also have a chance to get rare mods that are absolutely essential for being able to play in the late game. Only recently I finished building every frame (including all the primes) and that was around my 400 hour in game mark. However, I had spent most of my time before that trying to unlock most of the solar map and building new weapons. In a two week period I was able to farm for and build almost 80% of the frames. That being said, I will start off with a list of my most recommended frames.

**Top Recommended Frames**

1.  [Rhino](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Rhino_%28Warframe%29) - Acquired by fighting Jackal on Fossa, Venus. I highly recommend that you get this frame as soon as you can. Rhino is, in my opinion, the best low level/low skill warframe. His Iron Skin ability gives players a lot of wiggle room in how much damage they can take, allowing them to do higher level missions that they may not have been able to do previously due to being too squishy. His Roar ability also gives you wiggle room in the damage department. A Level 3 Roar will give you a 50% damage boost for 15 seconds at base values (A max power build will give you 142% damage which is HUGE). I'm very glad that you had him on your list, I'd recommend building him as soon as you possibly can. 

2.  [Nova](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Nova_%28Warframe%29) - Acquired by fighting Raptor on Naamah, Europa. Once you get the proper mods Nova is an incredibly versatile frame, great for solo play, boss farming, and credit farming (speed nova on dark sector defense). Having a nova will also allow you to get in with groups for doing just about any mission.

3.  [Loki](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Loki_%28Warframe%29) - Acquired by fighting the Hyena Pack on Psamathe, Neptune. His prime version is my absolute favorite for running Capture, Rescue, Sabotage, Spy, and Survival Missions. His Invisibility ability allows him to be completely untargetable (and undetectable) by enemies. His Radial Disarm ability is also excellent when paired with the Irradiated Disarm Syndicate mod (this causes Radial Disarm to do Radiation Damage, which causes enemies to attack each other in confusion). I regard him as more of a solo frame, but this allows you do some less commonly run missions by yourself when you're trying to complete the solar map. 

4.  [Nekros](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Nekros_%28Warframe%29) - Acquired by fighting Lephantis in the Orokin Derelict Assassination missions. I highly recommend fighting Lephantis with Nova because her slow greatly reduces the attack animations and leaves his windows of vulnerability open for much longer. Nekros is a frame that is great for farming resources via his Desecrate ability. You can get into just about any Survival mission with a Nekros depending on the build you have. 

5.  [Trinity](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trinity_%28Warframe%29) - Acquired by fighting Captain Vor and Lt. Lech Kril on Iliad, Phobos. While this is the very last planet, Trinity is one of the best and most underrated frames in Warframe. With Trinity you can easily get into whichever Syndicate rep farming spot is most popular (currently Draco). This is great for you because you don't have to do ANYTHING except for cast your Energy Vampire ability while your weapons will be leveling up like crazy. I enjoy running her in Tower Survival because I can run groups that are much squishier and require much more energy, but can make it much longer because I'm able to heal and replenish their energy.

**Other Thoughts**

Frost just barely missed the list at #6 only because his strengths only reside within Mobile Defense and Defense missions and it can take some more advanced mod setups in order to have an effective build. Please note that these are my personal top 5 recommendations and you may enjoy a different style of gameplay. I did not put in [Limbo](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Limbo_%28Warframe%29), [Mesa](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mesa_%28Warframe%29), [Mirage](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Mirage_%28Warframe%29), and [Vauban](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Vauban_%28Warframe%29) because I regard them as more advanced frames not only in difficulty of acquisition, but playstyle and mod requirements. Do note that Vauban is incredibly difficult to get by trying to catch alerts with his parts. It took me 8 months to get him completely built by acquiring him naturally. If you decide to purchase any warframe, this is the one you should get.

**Conclusion**

Don't focus too hard on getting all the warframes. Weapons are also a huge part of the game. If you can get into the missions, the [Boltor Prime](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Boltor_Prime) is the BEST jack-of-all-trades weapon you can get. Do also note that there is no "best" warframe. Each one has their own strengths and weaknesses, which allows for interesting and varied gameplay if you decide to build a lot of them as well as learn the skills for each one. Good luck and happy grinding!

Comment: Nekros is a very late candidate as Derelict mission are for more experienced players, isn't it? The other warframes I would rank by planetary access order then.

Comment: @CodeClown - Yes and No to that. Derelict missions aren't too bad as long as you have at least one higher leveled person to carry you through. If you're a competent player and keep your eye on the recruiting channel, you can get into groups fairly easily. I often host ODA missions for new players so they can get Nekros parts and get used to the Derelict maps.